# For vector control inner loop Iqs & Ids, how to match with the per-phase equivalent circuit currents of induction motor in real?

Tags: induction-motor, vector-control, equivalent-circuit

[image]

[image]

Although I can understand both of the diagrams above, I am confused about the relations between them.

As marked in the per-phase equivalent circuit of a 3-phase induction motor above, we assume the 3-phase value is the vector sum of three per-phase equivalent circuits separated by 120 degree phase position.

Then according to the vector sum of three separated per-phase equivalent circuits:

- the red arrow current signal = Ids (which is the magneting current from stator for the rotor to build magnetic field)?
- Iexc = Iqs (which is the stator magnetic field current)?
- Finally the cross product of Ids x Iqs is proportional to the torque output?

If it doesn't, how to match the equivalent circuit currents to the vector control dq currents?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, the torque output is proportional do the active current (Iq) and flux is proportional to the reactive current (Id). You have to consider the machine model in both d and q frames separately. Please see source link below.

[MODEL OF A THREE-PHASE INDUCTION MOTOR](https://www.tntech.edu/engineering/pdf/cesr/ojo/asuri/Chapter3.pdf)